# Autocomplete showed only 2 seconds and then disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an autocomplete field that is ok for 1-2 seconds, but then disappear...

```
 holder.ed = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)      
convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MyApplication.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
                    new String[] {"elementa","elementb","elementc","elementd"}
                );
            holder.autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This code is into "getView" of baseadapeter

Comment: what disappears? the autocomplete or the suggestion list?

Comment: yes!!! I cannot make a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the auto complete inside a list view. I think the view looses the focus on itself due to item expansion.
You can verify this by setting a onFocusChange listener. 
If that is the case, try preventing your view from loosing the focus.

Alternatively, if possible, change the list view to a linear layout.

Comment: no, I need a relative layout.. How can I prevent the loosing of focus?

Comment: I have now take the event that "lose focus", but then? (and I saw that with virtual emulator is ok, instead with smartphone lose focus..)

Comment: you can try requesting it again or maybe increase the item initial size so that the list view does not request it

Comment: I have a listener on focus and I saw that when I type on autocomplete, every character sent a "lose focus" (which is a system.out linked to the event of !hasFocus)

Comment: that makes me think it is related to the hieght of the item in the list view. try increasing it to see if you stop loosing the focus.